# Visualizing $ \bigwedge^k V $ and $ \bigwedge^k (V^*) $

Tags: linear-algebra

### Fixing some notations

Given a vector space $ V $ over a field $ \mathbb R $ of characteristic 0 let's define
$$
\bigwedge\nolimits^k V = \{\text{$ \overbrace{V^*\times\cdots \times V^*}^{\text{$ k $ times}}\to \mathbb R $ $ k $-linear and alternating}\}\qquad \bigwedge\nolimits_k V = \{\text{$ \overbrace{V\times\cdots \times V}^{\text{$ k $ times}}\to \mathbb R $ $ k $-linear and alternating}\}
$$
for every $ k\geqq 1 $ in such a way that the tensors in $ \bigwedge^k V $ are *contravariant* tensors and the ones in $ \bigwedge_k V $ are *covariant*.

If $ \phi\colon V\to W $ is a map between vector spaces, let's denote with
$$
\bigwedge^\nolimits k \phi\colon \bigwedge^\nolimits k V\rightarrow \bigwedge^\nolimits k W\qquad \bigwedge_\nolimits k \phi\colon \bigwedge_\nolimits k V\leftarrow \bigwedge_\nolimits k W
$$
the linear mappings
$$
\Bigl(\bigwedge^\nolimits k \phi\Bigr)(A)(\beta^1,\dots,\beta^k) = A(\phi^*(\beta^1),\dots,\phi^*(\beta^k))\qquad \Bigl(\bigwedge_\nolimits k \phi\Bigr)(\eta)(v_1,\dots,v_k) = \eta(\phi(v_1),\dots,\phi(v_k))
$$
where $ A\in \bigwedge^k V $, $ \eta\in \bigwedge_k V $ and $ \alpha^1,\dots,\alpha^k\in V^* $, $ v_1,\dots,v_k\in V $.

We then define the wedge products in the usual way as
$$
A\wedge B = \frac{(k + l)!}{k!l!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k + l}}(\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) \sigma(A\otimes B)\qquad \omega\wedge \eta = \frac{(k + l)!}{k!l!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k + l}}(\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) \sigma(\omega\otimes \eta)\qquad 
$$
for $ A\in \bigwedge^k V $, $ B\in \bigwedge^l V $ and $ \omega\in \bigwedge_k V $, $ \eta\in \bigwedge_l V $. In this way $ \bigwedge^k V $ satisfies the universal property of the exterior product of $ k $ copies of $ V $, and $ \bigwedge_k V $ satisfies the universal property of the exterior product of $ k $ copies of $ V^* $.

Thus we obtain two functors
$$
\bigwedge^\nolimits k({-})\colon \mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb R}\to \mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb R}\qquad \bigwedge_\nolimits k({-})\colon \mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb R}^\text{op}\to \mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb R}
$$
on the category of vector spaces over $ \mathbb R $ (the first one *covariant* and the other one *contravariant*), and I know that
$$
\bigwedge^\nolimits k({-}) = \bigwedge_\nolimits k({-})^*\qquad \bigwedge_\nolimits k({-})\cong \bigwedge^\nolimits k({-})^*\cong \Bigl(\bigwedge^\nolimits k({-})\Bigr)^* \tag{1}\label{eqn:isos}
$$
where of course $ ({-})\colon \mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb R}^\text{op}\to \mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb R} $ is the obvious dual space functor.

### Where I need some clarifications

I don't have a specific question in mind. I would like to grasp the geometrical meaning of the spaces $ \bigwedge^k V $ and $ \bigwedge_k V $.

#### The determinant

For example, let's start from the determinant of an endomorphism $ \phi\colon V\to V $, where $ V $ is $ n $-dimensional. My lecturer defined it as the unique scalar $ \det\phi $ such that
$$
\Bigl(\bigwedge_\nolimits n\phi\Bigr)\eta = (\det\phi)\, \eta
$$
for every $ \eta\in \bigwedge_k V $. But for instance these [beautiful notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf) on exterior powers by Keith Conrad define the determinant of $ \phi $ as the unique scalar $ \det\phi $ such that
$$
(\bigwedge^\nolimits k \phi) A = (\det\phi)\, A
$$
for every $ A\in \bigwedge^k V $.

Of course, if we accept that the "right" definition is the second one, then what my lecturer is really definig is the determinant of $ \phi^* $. And using (\ref{eqn:isos}) or just by getting our hand a dirty a bit with permutations etc. we can show that $ \det\phi $ and $ \det\phi^* $ are equal.

But what does all of this *mean*? I know the geometrical significance of the determinant, and I would like to link it to these $ {}^k $ vs. $ {}_k $ stuff.

#### The wedge product

A another example, I know that given $ v_1,\dots,v_k\in V $ and $ \alpha^1,\dots,\alpha^k\in V^* $ then
$$
(v_1\wedge \dots\wedge v_k)(\alpha^1,\dots,\alpha^k) = (\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge \alpha^k)(v_1,\dots,v_k)
$$
where the first wedge product is taken with respect to $  \bigwedge V^k $ and the second one with respect to $ \bigwedge_k V $. (here of course to compute $ v_1\wedge \dots\wedge v_k $ we're exploiting the isomorphism $ V\cong V^{**} $ between $ V $ and it's double dual).

But this makes things even more confusing for me! What's the difference between the wedge product of *vectors* and the wedge product of *forms*? Is there something "geometrically significant" which I should be aware of?

Comment: See my posts (this list is non-exhaustive): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748517/geometric-meaning-of-the-rising-and-the-lowering-of-indices/4748695#4748695 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757509/deriving-the-general-form-of-the-exterior-product-from-the-quotient-space-defini/4757625#4757625 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528776/geometric-interpretation-of-intersection-product/4528791#4528791 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50342/concrete-example-illustrating-the-interior-product/4648698#4648698

Comment: Once we establish that the elements of ${\bigwedge}^nV$ represent the volume of the space $V$ itself, then we start to understand that the determinant is the factor by which a linear transformation scales volumes. This can be made even more explicit by considering the change-of-coordinates formula for integrals.

Answer (score 1):

I consider $\bigwedge^kV^*$ to be the easier to understand. First, I consider an element of $V^*$ to be a measuring instruments. It defines a function on $V$ whose level sets are parallel hyperplanes, so its value at a point in $V$ tells you which hyperplane the point lies on. Rescaling the dual vector is like changing the units of measurement.

If $\dim V=n$, then $\xi\in\bigwedge^nV^*$ measures the $n$-dimensional volume of an $n$-dimensional parallelopiped in $V$. Again, changing $\xi$ is like changing the units of volume.

A $k$-form is a way to measure $k$-volume of a $k$-dimensional parallelopiped in $V$. The key difference is that, even if the $k$-form is nonzero, the $k$-volume of some $k$-parallelopipeds could be zero.